# How to delete multiple ids in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

i want delete multiple

```
_ids = ['123', '234', '345'];

_ids.forEach(_id => {
  await model.deleteOne({ _id });
});
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use deleteMany from mongoose

```
ids = ['123', '234', '345'];

await model.deleteMany({_id:{$in:ids}})
```

OR else

you also did good job similarly

```
_ids = ['123', '234', '345'];

_ids.map(async id => {
 await model.remove({ _id:id });  
});
```

Comment: await model.deleteMany().where('_id').in(ids);

is it possible?

Comment: this is string values not a ObjectId. How to add ObjectId before this ids array ?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, use [deleteMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany) of mongoose,

```
_ids = ['123', '234', '345'];

model.deleteMany({_id: { $in: _ids}}, function(err) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple

```
ids = ['123', '234', '345'];

await model.deleteMany({_id:{$in:ids}})
```